# Vue2 js scrolling call function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there anyway to call a method on vue after the viewer scrolled certain amount of page percentage?

For example, i would like to run a method to display an offer after the viewer has scrolled 80% of the page from top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
      const offsetTop = window.scrollY || 0;
      const percentage = (offsetTop * 100) / document.body.scrollHeight;

      // Do something with the percentage
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Note** If you want to do something ( for example `task()` ) with a condition that the percentage is ***equal or greater*** than some value you must considering a data variable container that how many times that condition is true and do the operation **just one time** after that.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      reached: false, // checker container
    };
  },
  methods: {
    task() {
      console.log("Triggered just one time >= 80");
    },
    handleScroll(event) {
      // ... After calculating the percentage ...
      if (percentage >= 80) {
        if (!this.reached) {
          this.task();
          this.reached = true;
        }
      } else this.reached = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

#### [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-stonebraker-hqgbk?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: sir i have a question, what if i want to do HTTP get  and show new component and everytime i scroll to 80% and show the content, isnt the page will get higher? and is the function still working? isnt my page will be higher?

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp I explained it in the second section ( _`Note If you want to do something ...`_ )  and the code below it , isn't it helpful ? see the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-stonebraker-hqgbk?file=/src/App.vue) and check the console that might be something that you want if you implement it exactly there won't be a problem

Comment: thank you very much sir, God Bless You it works like a charm, Your demo help my life a lot :D